# what is ? in pagination hyper links

Tags: html, django, hyperlink, pagination

Hi im reading a book about django and in pagination template i see a ?  but i do not know why is it there.I searched but got no answer.

Here is the template :

```
<div class="pagination">
   <span class="step-links">
       {% if page.has_previous %}
           <a href="?page={{ page.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
       {% endif %}
   <span class="current">
       Page {{ page.number }} of {{ page.paginator.num_pages }}.
   </span>
   {% if page.has_next %}
       <a href="?page={{ page.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
   {% endif %}
   </span>
</div>
```

what is the question mark in the address of page in ???

Answer (score 2):

The `?` basically represents a query parameter in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

In many cases, the beginning of the query string is marked with a question mark and the various parameters that make up the query string are separated with an ampersand, but other syntaxes are also possible.

```
domain.com?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2&parameter3=value3
```